# Authenticating Service Accounts on Google Compute Engine with BigQuery, via R Studio Server

Tags: r, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

I'm looking to call BigQuery from R Studio, installed on a Google Compute Engine.

I have the bq python tool installed on the instance, and I was hoping to use its service accounts and system() to get R to call bq command line tool and so get the data.

However, I run into authentication problems, where it asks for a browser key.  I'm pretty sure there is no need to get the key due to the service account, but I don't know how to construct the authetication from with R (it runs on RStudio, so will have multiple users)

I can get an authetication token like this:

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
metadata <-  getURL('http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/service-accounts/default/token')
tokendata <- fromJSON(metadata)

tokendata$$access_token
```

But how do I then use this to generate a .bigqueryrc token?  Its the lack of this that triggers the authetication attempt.

This works ok:

```
system('/usr/local/bin/bq')
```

showing me bq is installed ok.

But when I try something like:

```
   system('/usr/local/bin/bq ls')
```

I get this:

```
Welcome to BigQuery! This script will walk you through the process of initializing your .bigqueryrc configuration file.

First, we need to set up your credentials if they do not already exist.


******************************************************************
** No OAuth2 credentials found, beginning authorization process **
******************************************************************

Go to the following link in your browser:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbigquery&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline

Enter verification code: You have encountered a bug in the BigQuery CLI. Google engineers monitor and answer questions on Stack Overflow, with the tag google-bigquery:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=google-bigquery

etc.
```

Edit:

I have managed to get bq functioning from RStudio system() commands, by skipping the authetication by logging in to the terminal as the user using RStudio, autheticating there by signing in via the browser, then logging back to RStudio and calling system("bq ls") etc..so this is enough to get me going :)

However, I would still prefer it if BQ can be autheticated within RStudio itself, as many users may log in and I'll need to autheticate via terminal for all of them.  And from the service account documentation, and the fact I can get an authetication token, hints at this being easier.

Comment: Maybe you want to try Hadley Wickham's [bigrquery](https://github.com/hadley/bigrquery) package.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go - I had a fiddle with http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-r-client/ as well, but its unsupported now.  I'd like read-write access if possible that bigrquery doesn't provide, but at least it may show how to authenticate :)

Comment: ..sadly, it didn't work.  Got stuck at "Autheticating in Browser" and sent a request to http://localhost:8787/custom/OAuth/cred?state=Rz4cirpabP&code=XXXXXXX

Comment: Double-check to make sure you created the instance with the BigQuery scope enable. If it is not enabled, bq won't be authenticated, and the access token returned from the metadata server won't have rights to use the BigQuery API.

Comment: Dear Brian, thanks for the aid.  I'm sure the BQ scope is enabled, as I can log in from terminal and list and create datasets.  It seems I can autheticate if I do it via terminal, but not via R Studio

Comment: It sounds like the authentication mechanism is baked in to the bq tool.  I expect you'll need to modify R Studio to pull the bearer token from the metadata server and include it with its requests.  That work is probably beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question, though.

Comment: Hi Mark, could possibly briefly explain how to install RStudio on Google Compute Engine?

Comment: Hi @bquast, well briefly you start up a Debian install on GCE, open the right firewalls, install R, Rstudio done, but Rstudio was beta when  tried it so some workarounds were needed then.  I'll be doing it again soonish, but I have my notes from before as a step by step guide here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/13fhgFo7FcrdotFPwFTEa1BR4r7L-rOtoFjQEiLkepAc/edit?usp=sharing - please take with pinch of salt as things may have changed since, but at very least you can use the references to help your install.

Comment: thanks, a lot. I got most of it right, but installing it requires a dependency (lib0.9.8) which I installed manually, however, it still gives me an error when I install rstudio, it says, rsession, not found. will have a look at this and try to work it out. cheers!

Comment: Hi @bquast, I remember needing to install that older lib0.9.8 as well, guess that hasn't updated in the meantime.  It sounds like Rstudio is looking for R in a different place to where you installed it? Perhaps you installed under just your own user?

Comment: thanks, I hadn't thought about that, though I am install using sudo, so normally i shouldn't right? is there another way to install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the time being, you need to run 'bq init' from the command line to set up your credentials prior to invoking bq from a script in GCE. However, the next release of bq will include support for GCE service accounts via a new --use_gce_service_account flag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - ok cool, so wait a bit and it'll be available.  I think I got caught out by the two different "service accounts" that are talked about in the help files, led me down a blind alley :)  BTW, where can I subscribe to for when the update will occur?